# ¿Por qué este es un bucle infinito?

Tags: javascript

```
let platicar= true
do {

  let platica= confirm ("quieres hablar conmigo?")  

  if (platica) {

    platicar= true

    alert ("HOla")
  } else {
    platicar = false 
  }

} while ( platicar = true)
```

No entiendo porque este es un bucle infinito. estoy usando false and true para poner las condiciones y no funciona eso. quiero que si responde que no quiere platicar se salga del loop, pero si si quiere platicar, se haga lo establecido, y al terminar eso, vuelva a preguntar que si quiero platicar, hasta que ya no quiera platicar.

Comment: La comparación es con **doble igual (`==`)** o **triple igual (`===`)**.

Answer (score 6):

En el comando while, al usar el operador `=`, hace una asignación de valor y es lo que se toma como resultado, debes comparar con `==` o bien `===` de esta forma

```
while ( platicar === true)
```

Comment: solo tiene que dejar "while ( platicar )" comparar boleanos no tiene sentido.

Comment: Me parece que esta en proceso de aprendizaje, en su defecto puede comparar con `platica` y ahorrarse todos los if's, pero le servirán de apoyo

Comment: Graciassss, si era lo de los iguales

Comment: Realmente vale con poner `while (platicar)`, comparar un booleano con `true` es redundante.